# How to classify continuous/differentiable maps from $T^2$ to $U(N)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, index-theory

I read a [physics paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3324), of which the main idea is based on the topological classification of maps from 3-torus to the space of $N\times N$ unitary matrices. To quote their equation (4), which gives a winding number:
$$W(U)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_{T^3} dtdk_xdk_y U^{-1}\partial_t U\cdot[U^{-1}\partial_{k_x} U,U^{-1}\partial_{k_y} U],$$
where $(t,k_x,k_y)\in S^1\times S^1\times S^1\cong T^3$, and $U:=U(t,k_x,k_y)$ taking values of N-dimensional unitary matrices. The formula comes from [this math paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-62/issue-3/Some-remarks-on-the-paper-of-Callias--Axial-anomalies/cmp/1103904396.full), which is not really comprehensible to me given my limited math background.

Now I'm interested in the classification (up to homotopy) of maps from 2-torus to the space of $N\times N$ unitary matrices, is this already well developed? Any explanation or reference will be appreciated.

PS. I'm familiar with the language of fundamental groups (but not many sophisticated theorems) and a little bit homology. Also some basics on differentiable geometry. If possible, please explain in a way accessible to me, but if this means too much compromise, just go ahead and shower me with the proper mathematics.

Comment: Classification up to what (homotopy, homeomorphism, ...)? What kind of maps (e.g., are they required to be group homomorphisms)?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: I suppose up to homotopy. As for what kind of maps, I thought "continuous maps/diffentiable maps" was enough information, because I (maybe naively) had in mind that all continuous maps from $S^1$ to $S^1$ are completely classified up to homotopy by winding number. I'm expecting something similar or perhaps weaker.

Comment: In addition to Neil's answer: also there was a series of papers about "torus homotopy groups/sets" in late 40s by Ralph Fox; you can "universally" compute them for any space if you already know usual homotopy groups with action of fundamental group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are asking about the structure of the set $M=[T^2,U(N)]$ of homotopy classes of maps from $T^2$ to $U(N)$.  The functor $H_1$ gives a map $M\to\text{Hom}(H_1(T^2),H_1(U(n)))$, and standard calculations show that $H_1(T^2)=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $H_1(U(N))=\mathbb{Z}$, so we end up with a map $\phi\colon M\to\mathbb{Z}^2$.  We can use the group structure on $U(N)$ to make $M$ into a group, and it is standard that $\phi$ is a homomorphism with respect to this structure.

If we let $p_i$ denote the $i$'th projection $T^2\to S^1=U(1)\subset U(N)$, then $\phi(p_1)=(1,0)$ and $\phi(p_2)=(0,1)$, so $\phi$ is surjective.

In fact, $\phi$ is injective as well.  One way to see this is to check that the multiplication map $U(1)\times SU(N)\to U(N)$ is a homeomorphism, so $[T^2,U(n)]=[T^2,U(1)]\times[T^2,SU(N)]$.  The first factor is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ again.  The second factor is trivial, because $T^2$ is $2$-dimensional, and $SU(N)$ is $2$-connected (as one can prove using $SU(2)=S^3$ and the standard fibrations $SU(N)\to SU(N+1)\to S^{2N+1}$).

For another point of view, one can argue using the above fibrations that $M$ is independent of $N$, so we can take $N=\infty$, in which case $M$ becomes the complex $K$-theory group $KU^1(T^2)$.

UPDATE: We can write an integral formula as follows.  For $k=1,2$ let $i_k\:S^1\to T^2$ be the $k$'th axis inclusion.  Then the $k$'th component of $\phi(f)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ is just the ordinary winding number of the composite
$$ g_k = (S^1 \xrightarrow{i_k} T^2 \xrightarrow{f} U(N) \xrightarrow{\det} U(1)=S^1). $$
If we identify $S^1$ with the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, this is just
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{S^1} \frac{g'_k(z)}{g_k(z)}\, dz. $$

Comment: +1, this looks exactly like what I'm looking for. In the case of differentiable maps, is there a calculus-theoretic formula for $\phi$, e.g. something like the one quoted in my original post?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: By the way, what would be a good source of learning these topics? I'm primarily interested in classifications of maps from $T^n$ to manifolds and submanifolds of $U(N)$.

Comment: You should learn about $K$-theory.  $K^*(T^n)$ is always an exterior algebra on $n$ generators, and $[T^n,U(N)]=KU^1(T^n)$ provided that $n<2N$.